# How do I add ReactJS to a VSCode Extension WebView?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, webpack, vscode-extensions

I have been trying to add ReactJS to my VSCode extension project, and for some reason I am just not getting a page to render. Webpack doesn't seem to be transpiling my TSX to regular javascript and my extensions web view is just a blank page. I found and tried to follow [this blog post](https://isamatov.com/create-vscode-extension-with-react/) but the example project doesn't even compile. The logic mentioned in the post seems completely sound, but when I try to implement it I get no where. I've even [consulted ChatGPT to no results](https://chat.openai.com/share/9484e71e-78e1-47ff-8cc4-acf5cad4b8c7).

my `_getHtmlForWebview()` function looks like

```js
    private _getHtmlForWebview(webview: vscode.Webview) {

        const scriptUri = webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, 'src', 'index.tsx'));
        const microlightUri = webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, 'media', 'scripts', 'microlight.min.js'));
        const tailwindUri = webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, 'media', 'scripts', 'showdown.min.js'));
        const showdownUri = webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, 'media', 'scripts', 'tailwind.min.js'));

        const nonce = getNonce();

        return `<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; img-src vscode-resource: https:; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';style-src vscode-resource: 'unsafe-inline' http: https: data:;">
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="root"></div>
                <script src="${scriptUri}"></script>
            </body>
            </html>`;
    }
```

My App.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

function App() {
    return <div>
            <h1>
                Hello World!
            <h1/>
            I'm a React App.
        </div>
}

export default App;
```

and index.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
```

my tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "lib": [
            "ES2020",
            "dom"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true,
      /* enable all strict type-checking options */
        /* Additional Checks */
        // "noImplicitReturns": true, /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
        // "noUnusedParameters": true,  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
      "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

and my webpack.config.js

```
//@ts-check

'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

//@ts-check
/\*\* @typedef {import('webpack').Configuration} WebpackConfig \*\*/

/\*\* @type WebpackConfig \*/
const extensionConfig = {
  target: 'node', // VS Code extensions run in a Node.js-context  -\> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/
    mode: 'none', // this leaves the source code as close as possible to the original (when packaging we set this to 'production')

  entry: './src/extension.ts', // the entry point of this extension,  -\> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(\__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: \[
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  \],
  externals: {
    'playwright-core': 'commonjs2 playwright-core',
    vscode: 'commonjs vscode' // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -\> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
    // modules added here also need to be added in the .vscodeignore file
  },
  resolve: {
    // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -\> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
    extensions: \['.ts','.tsx','.jsx', '.js'\]
  },
  module: {
    rules: \[
      {
        test: /\\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: \[
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        \]
      }
    \]
  },
  devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: "log", // enables logging required for problem matchers
  },
};
module.exports = \[ extensionConfig \];
```

```
src/
├── App.tsx
├── extension.ts
├── index.html
└── index.tsx
media/
├── main.js
└── scripts
    ├── microlight.min.js
    ├── showdown.min.js
    └── tailwind.min.js
```

I'm expecting a VSCode Extension Webview with the contents

```
 <div>
      <h1>
          Hello World!
      <h1/>
 I'm a React App.
 </div>
```

[image: Image of VS code with a red arrow pointing to an empty Webview extension on the left "Should be rendering React here." and another red arrow pointed at a line of html in the dev tools highlighing the tsx in index.tsx]

I've tried hard coding the name to bundle.js but that of course doesn't work.